# How can projection operators be expressed in form $\frac{1}{d} (I + \sum_i r_i \lambda_i)$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, quantum-information

How can projection operator be expressed in form $\frac{1}{d} (I + \sum_i r_i \lambda_i)$?

I was reading a paper and found out that the density matrix in $d$-dimensional Hilbert Space can be expressed in form

$$\frac{1}{d} (I + \sum_i r_i \lambda_i),$$

where $i = 1,2,\ldots,d^2-1$, $r_i$ are reals (with certain conditions), $\lambda_i$ is the generators of $SU(d)$ algebra, they are orthogonal in the sense that

$$tr(\lambda_i\lambda_j) = \delta_{ij}.$$

I was wondering is there a way to explicitly choose $n$ sets of $\{r_i\}$ to form a complete set of orthogonal basis, i.e. projection operators, just like in $2$-dimensional case, where

$$\frac{1}{2} (I \pm (a_1\sigma_1 + a_2 \sigma_2 + a_3 \sigma_3))$$

are the two orthogonal  projection operators, with $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ on unit sphere.

Comment: I am no specialist in group theory. In my answer I just test and confirm the formula on which you ask. I delete it because it is ugly, but if you go to your question you will see it. On the other hand, if none of the specialist will offer a simpler answer, you can use mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I started writing it, I will complete this answer to add some extra mathematical detail. As stated by lionelbrits, the $d^2-1$ Hermitian generators of $\mathrm{SU}(d)$ are traceless and orthonormal with respect to the Hilbert-Schmidt inner product
$$(A,B) = \mathrm{Tr} (A^{\dagger}B).$$
Therefore, along with the identity, these operators form a complete, orthonormal basis in the $d^2$-dimensional Hilbert space of operators acting on a $d$-dimensional Hilbert space of vectors. Any operator can be expanded as an appropriate linear combination of the basis operators; a Hermitian operator will have real expansion coefficients.

It is convenient to normalise the basis so that
$\mathrm{Tr} (\lambda_i\lambda_j) = d\delta_{ij}.$
This is achieved by multiplying by a factor $\sqrt{d}$ the generators normally used by mathematicians. This convention is consistent with the OP's use of Pauli matrices in the case $d=2$. With this normalisation, any rank-one projector $\Pi = \lvert \psi\rangle\langle\psi\rvert$ can be expanded as
$$\Pi  = \frac{1}{d}\left( I + \sum_{i=1}^{d^2-1}r_i\lambda_i \right),$$
where $r_i = \mathrm{Tr}(\Pi \lambda_i)=\langle\psi\rvert\lambda_i\lvert\psi\rangle$. The condition $\mathrm{Tr} (\Pi^2) = 1$ leads to the restriction
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{d^2-1}r_i^2 = d-1,$$
meaning that the $r_i$ are coordinates on a $(d^2-2)$ -sphere of radius $\sqrt{d-1}$.

If two rank-one projectors with expansion coefficients $\{r_i\}$ and  $\{s_i\}$ are orthogonal, one finds the condition $\sum_i r_is_i = \mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{s} = -1$. When $d=2$, this implies that $\mathbf{r} = -\mathbf{s}$, i.e. the projectors are described by antipodal points on the unit sphere. For $d>2$ this is no longer the case: instead one finds that the angle between $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{s}$ is
$$\theta = \arccos \left(\frac{-1}{d-1}\right)$$
if the projectors are orthogonal. This illustrates that the nice geometrical intuition afforded by the [Bloch sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere) when $d=2$ does not carry over so simply to higher dimensions.

Comment: Since not all $\{r_i\}$ on the $(d^2−2)$-sphere represent projection operator, does it mean there is no good expression for a projection operator using $\{r_i\}$ instead of $\lvert\psi\rangle$?

Comment: @Doris I think that all $\{r_i\}$ on the $(d^2-2)$-sphere do represent a projection operator.

Comment: I think the degrees of freedom of $\{r_i\}$ on the $(d^2-2)$-sphere are $d^2-2$, a projection operator only has $2d$ degrees of freedom. So I guess not all $\{ri$\} on the $(d^2−2)$-sphere represent projection operator.

Comment: @Doris Very good point. There are additional constraints arising from the restriction $\Pi^2 = \Pi$ which defines a projection operator. I will have a think about this.

Answer (score 3):

The generators you mention form a complete basis for traceless hermitian matrices. Thus, to express a hermitian matrix that has a non zero trace in this basis, you have to augment the basis with one more matrix that is trace orthogonal to the others, and the identity does the trick. You can verify that the number of matrices in your basis agrees with the number of degrees of freedom of a hermitian matrix.

Another useful fact is that the generators of $U(N)$ are exactly the matrices you listed. The identity matrix take care of the phase of unitary matrices.

Btw, the "dot product" for this basis is just the trace of the product of the two matrices, so you can use this to decompose an arbitrary Hermitian matrix in your basis.

Comment: how well I did that I deleted my ugly proof. But, why don't you place an answer? And what is "travels hermitian matrices"? What is that "travels"? What travels here? It is a typo error?

Comment: AUtocomplete on a tiny screen, sorry. What do you mean by place an answer?

Comment: sorry, post an answer. But I see you did.